# I have assigned my variable but output says: "local variable referenced before assignment"

Tags: python

I now figured out how to encrypt single files. Now I want to be able to encrypt all my text files & documents in a directory. I have encountered the following problem, I have assigned a variable but my terminal says :

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'enc' referenced before assignment.

I don't know how to fix this. I have tried making the variable global but it is not working.

```
import os
from Crypto import Random
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

extensions = ['docs', 'txt']

tree = '.'

def padding(s):
   return s + b"\0" * (AES.block_size - len(s) % AES.block_size)

def encrypt(message, key, key_size=256):
   message = padding(message)
   iv = Random.new().read(AES.block_size)
   cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
   return iv + cipher.encrypt(message)

def allfiles():
   for root, dirs, files in os.walk(tree):
       for file in files:
       if (file.endswith(tuple(extensions))):
            with open(file, 'rb') as fs:
                plaintext = fs.read()
                enc = encrypt(plaintext, key)
       with open(file, 'w') as fs:
            fs.write(enc)

       key = b'\xbf\xc0\x85)\x10nc\x94\x02)j\xdf\xcb\xc4\x94\x9d(\x9e[EX\xc8\xd5\xbfI{\xa2$\x05(\xd5\x18'


allfiles()
```

Comment: `enc` will not be defined if `file.endswith(tuple(extensions))` is `False`

Comment: @ThierryLathuille i added an else: to the statement, but it still throws the error. Shouldn't it go to the else and not give the error none the less?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you missed your indentation you should try something like this to put your writtings inside your `if` block

```
import os
from Crypto import Random
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

extensions = ['docs', 'txt']

tree = '.'

def padding(s):
   return s + b"\0" * (AES.block_size - len(s) % AES.block_size)

def encrypt(message, key, key_size=256):
   message = padding(message)
   iv = Random.new().read(AES.block_size)
   cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
   return iv + cipher.encrypt(message)

def allfiles():
   for root, dirs, files in os.walk(tree):
       for file in files:
       if (file.endswith(tuple(extensions))):
            with open(file, 'rb') as fs:
                plaintext = fs.read()
                enc = encrypt(plaintext, key)
            with open(file, 'w') as fs:
                fs.write(enc) # Here enc is defined in your if bloc for sure

            key = b'\xbf\xc0\x85)\x10nc\x94\x02)j\xdf\xcb\xc4\x94\x9d(\x9e[EX\xc8\xd5\xbfI{\xa2$\x05(\xd5\x18'
       else:
            print('file not encrypted') # enc is not defined


allfiles()
```